# Typescript - conditional mapped types

Tags: typescript, knockout.js

I would like to map a plain old Javascript type to an equivalent one using Knockout observables.

```
interface KnockoutObservableArray<T> { }
interface KnockoutObservable<T> { }

class CustomerDto {
    Name: string;
    PetLicenseNumbers: number[];
}

// manually mapped to Knockout-equivalent 
class CustomerDtoKo {
    Name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    PetLicenseNumbers: KnockoutObservableArray<number>;
}
```

I'm trying to use mapped types to do the above automatically but I couldn't
find a proper way to conditionally map arrays to `KnockoutObservableArray<U>` 
while mapping the scalars to `KnockoutObservable<U>`

```
type KnockoutType<T> = {
    //[K in keyof T] : KnockoutObservableArray<T[K][0]>
    [K in keyof T] : KnockoutObservable<T[K]>
}

type CustomerDtoKo2 = KnockoutType<CustomerDto>;
// gives
type CustomerDtoKo2 = {
    Name: KnockoutObservable<string>,
    PetLicenseNumbers: KnockoutObservable<number[]> // should be KnockoutObservableArray<number>
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you expect, [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) will help you:

```
type KnockoutType<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<infer U> ? 
      KnockoutObservableArray<U> : KnockoutObservable<T[K]>
}
```

Good luck!